# Facebook app remains logged in after using Facebook SDK authentication

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I have an app that uses Facebook SDK for fetching data such as user's friends, picture and so on.

After using the SSO feature, if the facebook app is installed on the device, it remains logged in, and gives notifications and so on.
I want to disable that - I just need to authenticate with my app and do simple facebook queries, I don't want the facebook app to open and stay in the background.

Any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

With the new Facebook SDK 3.0 there's a `Session#close()` method.